# Text output from tests using Visual Studio 2013 + Resharper + NUnit

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

After migrating from VS 2012 Pro to VS 2013 Pro, `Trace.Write()` inside a unit test doesn't seem to output to R#'s output window anymore.

Platform: Win7x64 + VS2013Pro + R#8.2 + Built-in NUnit.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Hate to say it, but works on my machine :)

Are you clearing the trace listeners at all, or writing from a background thread?

Comment: No fancy stuff happening :-|